# Time slowed down using `S.D.Stopwatch` on Azure

Tags: azure, time, azure-web-app-service, time-measurement

I just ran some code which reports its performance on an Azure Web Sites instance; the result seemed a little off.  I re-ran the operation, and indeed it seems consistent:  `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` sees an execution time of **12 seconds** for an operation that actually took more than **three *minutes*** (at least 3m16s).

```
Debug.WriteLine("Loading dataset in database ...");
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
ProcessDataset(CurrentDataSource.Database.Connection as SqlConnection, parser);
stopwatch.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Dataset loaded in database ({0}s)", stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
return (short)stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds;
```

This process runs in the context of a WCF Data Service "action" and seeds test data in a SQL Database (this is not production code).  Specifically, it:

1. Opens a connection to an Azure SQL Database,
2. Disables a null constraint,
3. Uses `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` to lock an empty table and load it using a buffered stream that retrieves a dataset (2.4MB) from Azure Blob Storage via the filesystem, decompresses it (GZip, 4.9MB inflated) and parses it (CSV, 349996 records, parsed with a custom `IDataReader` using `TextFieldParser`),
4. Updates a column of the same table to set a common value,
5. Re-enables the null constraint.

No less, no more; there's nothing particularly intensive going on, I figure the operation is mostly network-bound.

Any idea why time is slowing down?

Notes:

- Interestingly, timeouts for both the bulk insert and the update commands had to be increased (set to five minutes).  I read that the default is 30 seconds, which is more than the reported 12 seconds; hence, I conclude that `SqlClient` measures time differently.
- Reports from local execution seem perfectly correct, although it's consistently faster (4-6s using LocalDB) so it may just be that the effects are not noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds to get total time but it is wrong. Elapsed.Seconds is the  seconds component of the time interval represented by the TimeSpan structure. Please try stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds instead.

Comment: For some reason I completely missed your answer -- Thank you, I just tested it; my bad indeed.